# Using timers (onload)

Tags: javascript

Ok, firstly, I hardly know Javascript. I really don't know what I'm doing.
So, I have this code:

```
var interval_id = 0;
var prevent_bust = 0;


 // Event handler to catch execution of the busting script.
 window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ };

 // Continuously monitor whether busting script has fired.
 interval_id = setInterval(function() {
   if (prevent_bust > 0) {  // Yes: it has fired. 
     prevent_bust -= 2;     // Avoid further action.
     // Get a 'No Content' status which keeps us on the same page.
     window.top.location = 'http://vadremix.com/204.php';
   }
 }, 1);

   function clear ()
   {
       clearInterval(interval_id);
   }

   window.onload="setTimeout(clear (), 1000)";
```

After 1 second I want to clear the interval set earlier. This isn't working. How would I do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you substitute the last line with `window.onload = function() { setTimeout(clear, 1000); }`, it should do OK.

There are two errors in your code:

- `window.onload` should be a `function`, rather than a string (`"..."`),
- `setTimeout` accepts a function (`clear`), rather than the result from the function (`clear()`)

By the way, these are some good places to learn JavaScript:

- [QuirksMode](http://quirksmode.org/)
- [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs)

Comment: Thank you! Also, thanks for the links, I've been meaning to learn JavaScript for some time but never got around to it, obviously